# you have entered too many arguments

Tags: excel-formula, arguments, excel-2010

I received an error , **You have entered too few arguments,** can someone help me check whats the error?

Now i have the % for the whole team that meet the TAT of 15 days and never meet (example 95%), but now i would like to calculate for individuals to see who did not meet the TAT of 15 days and are pulling the % as a team down.

my formula is as follow:

```
=COUNTIFS(DSE_Pyt[Payment Done By],H88,DSE_Pyt[Month],F6,
 COUNTIFS( DSE_Pyt[For Undisputed Pymt, TAT <=15BD ?],"Y",
 DSE_Pyt[Month],F$6)/(COUNTIFS( DSE_Pyt[For Undisputed Pymt, TAT <=15BD ?],"Y",
 DSE_Pyt[Month],F6)+COUNTIFS( DSE_Pyt[For Undisputed Pymt, TAT <=15BD ?],"N",
 DSE_Pyt[Month],F6)))
```

Simple to say , i would like to calculate the person individual stats on whether how many TAT did she meet divided by the total orders she submit.

the team formula ( that worked ) :

=COUNTIFS( DSE_Pyt[For Undisputed Pymt, TAT <=15BD ?],"Y", DSE_Pyt[Month],F$6)/(COUNTIFS( DSE_Pyt[For Undisputed Pymt, TAT <=15BD ?],"Y", DSE_Pyt[Month],F$6)+COUNTIFS( DSE_Pyt[For Undisputed Pymt, TAT <=15BD ?],"N", DSE_Pyt[Month],F$6))

Comment: Your formula is ill formed, you can't insert a `COUNTIFS` as a *range argument* inside another `COUNTIFS`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to calculate for individual stats(for how well they do) for different measurement for a specific month

Comment: Without any sample data, context or logic description it is impossible to figure out what your formula should be. The only thing that strikes is what A.S.H. already said. If you need more help than that, edit your question and provide more context. Edit your question to do that. Don't post that as a comment. Then leave a comment to alert people who follow the thread.

Comment: I suggest that you post an example data and some description or  equation of the desired result. As it stands, we only can see that the formula isn't correct and that `COUNTIFS` is unlikely to be the solution.

Comment: I have edited m questions , please help take a look . Appreciate.

Comment: How about that sample data?

Comment: Its just a number of Yes and No in the Column that i wish to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two problems

1. Your numerator seems to be incomplete

   =COUNTIFS(DSE_Pyt[Payment Done By],H88,DSE_Pyt[Month],F6,
    COUNTIFS(DSE_Pyt[For Undisputed Pymt, TAT <=15BD ?],"Y", DSE_Pyt[Month],F$6)

   The second `COUNTIFS()` appears to be the one of the range of the first countifs  - if this is going to result in a range then where is the criteria for this range ?
2. There seems to be a unbalanced ')'   (closing bracket at the end of your formula)